# Check whether two elements exist in same sublist of a list Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have a list sublists that I would like to search and check if two individual elements are within the same sublist. So for example, with 16 list elements in a randomized order,:

```
list=[[], [9, 10], [1, 2, 8, 13], [0, 3, 6, 14], [5, 7, 11], [],]
#Max number of classes
MaxN=5
for k in range(0,MaxN):
    for i in list[k]:
      ##if (check whether i exists in same sublist as i+1):
          continue
        else
          foo()
```

So that connections between [9, 10], [1, 2], [1, 8], [1, 13], [2, 8], [2, 13], [8, 13], [0, 3], [0, 6], [0, 14], [3, 6], [3, 14], [6, 14], [5, 7], [5, 11], [7, 11] will all be skipped, and the operation foo will be performed on the rest of the list.

I tried:

```
for k in range(0,MaxN):
    for i in list[k]:
        if list[i]==list[i+1]:
           print 'skipped'
        else:
           print 'included'
```

But I get a list index out of range error, which I don't seem to understand.

Comment: I don't understand the question ... you can post more examples ? or with some input what is the expected output

Comment: can you explain why  `[9,10][1,2][1,8][1,13],[2,8],...,[7,11]` come about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
>>> output=[]
>>> list=[[], [9, 10], [1, 2, 8, 13], [0, 3, 6, 14], [5, 7, 11], []]
>>> for l in list:
      for i in range(len(l)):
         for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
            output.append([l[i],l[j]])


>>> output
[[9, 10], [1, 2], [1, 8], [1, 13], [2, 8], [2, 13], [8, 13], [0, 3], [0, 6], [0, 14], [3, 6], [3, 14], [6, 14], [5, 7], [5, 11], [7, 11]]
```

After getting output list, you can simply try with the help of "`in`" keyword:

```
>>> for k in range(5):     #or range(maxN)
      if (list[k] in output):
          print("skipped")
      else:
          print("included")    

included
skipped
included
included
included
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  I read your problem as, you're trying to look at a list, and see if any of its elements are in any of the subsquent lists.  If so you want to do something like the following (**NOTE** I changed your variable to `my_list`, calling something `list` in python is dangerous because you can no longer use it to make actual lists)

```
my_lists=[[], [9, 10], [1, 2, 8, 13], [0, 3, 6, 14], [5, 7, 11], [],]
n_sub_lists = len(my_list)

for k in range(0,n_sub_lists):
    for i in my_lists[k]:
        for j in range(k, len(n_sub_lists)):
            if i in my_lists[j]:
                continue
            else:
                foo()
```

I also removed your `MaxN` variable because I wasn't sure of it's purpose.  If I was mistaken there please comment and I'll update appropriately

Comment: This does not quite answer my question, but I was not the one who downvoted.